# 80's War/Science Fiction Anime?

Tags: story-identification, anime

I need help identifying a really old obscure anime movie.

I remember when I was a young kid, an anime movie was on TV and it was the first anime I had ever watched. I can only remember this one obscure detail about it though.

I watched it maybe when I was 7 or 8 (I'm 25 now), so it must have come out in the 80's or 90's.

The only thing I remember is the ending: there was a large explosion and a buff dude was carrying a woman out of the explosion/flames. I'm not sure but I think it might have been a robot/war movie. I also think there was tanks/other weapons in the movie as well.

Please help, this anime has plagued me for years and I really want to know what it was called.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What country was this in, and what language?  Was it  subtitled?

Comment: Thanks! I live in the US. It wasn't subtitled, it was dubbed.

Comment: Can you tell us about what year it was, and about where it was?  I know Robotech (all three arc's) was on television in Salt Lake city area in the mid-1980's.